Crimping the JST SUR connector?
I have ordered some PCB assemblies using the JST SUR headers (JLCPCB) and some wires with JST SUR connectors attached (Digikey). They are easy enough to use but I haven't found any information on how I could make my own wires with these connectors. It's a 32AWG wire and a 0.8 mm pitch connector.
https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Wire-To-Board-Connector_JST-BM02B-SURS-TF-LF-SN_C385130.html
https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/A02SUR02SUR32W102B/9947427
https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/02SUR-32S/1300326
https://www.jst.com/products/insulation-displacement-connectors-wire-to-board-type/sur-connector/
Apparently this is an insulation displacement connector, not a crimp style connector?

Are you sure you want to build these yourself? For lower volumes it will be cheaper to buy premade assemblies than buying the tool. For higher volumes you need someone who is used at working with cable assembly.

JST seems to have a couple of options
If I understand correctly, the
HPD-M2A hand press is $3,300 CAD and the required tool H2-SUR30ED-X to fit in the press is another $13k CAD.

Yep that's correct, these always use a base tool + an inserted module for the specific connector.
